React useCanonical hook
I have created a useCanonical hook which is meant for managing the <link rel="canonical" href="..." /> element in head (for SEO).
This code relies on a custom useIsMounted() hook which simply returns a cached function that when called returns whether or not the component is currently mounted.
function useCanonical() {
  const canonical = useRef(null);
  const isMounted = useIsMounted();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if(canonical.current) {
        canonical.current.remove();
        canonical.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return useCallback((href) => {
    if(!isMounted()) return;

    if(!canonical.current) {
      canonical.current = document.createElement('link');
      canonical.current.setAttribute('rel', 'canonical');
      document.head.appendChild(canonical.current);
    }

    canonical.current.setAttribute('href', href);
  }, [isMounted]);
}

Usage:
const setCanonical = useCanonical();

useEffect(() => {
    setCanonical('https://example.com/page');
}, [setCanonical]);

Note that by default, a page should not have a canonical, which is why it is being removed on unmount.
Any thoughts on how it can be perfected or improved?

Do you use SSR? If not, this might change nothing for SEO.
